# Runnin a Hipi map reduce program

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

I am trying to run HIPI map reduce example (Downloader). I have added the hipi jars to the build path but getting below error on execution.

My command looks like,

```
hadoop jar Downloader.jar Downloader  ./hipi/hipi.txt ./hipi/output.hib 1
```

My input file `hipi.txt` contains three URLs

Error log:

```
> Output HIB: ./hipi/ 14/01/12 02:39:08 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use
> GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should
> implement Tool for the same. Found host successfully: 0 Tried to get 1
> nodes, got 1 14/01/12 02:39:09 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input
> paths to process : 1 First n-1 nodes responsible for 3 images Last
> node responsible for 3 images 14/01/12 02:39:10 INFO mapred.JobClient:
> Running job: job_201401050058_0010 14/01/12 02:39:12 INFO
> mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0% 14/01/12 02:40:10 INFO
> mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201401050058_0010_m_000000_0,
> Status : FAILED Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> hipi.imagebundle.HipiImageBundle  at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
> Downloader$DownloaderMapper.map(Downloader.java:61)   at
> Downloader$DownloaderMapper.map(Downloader.java:1)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)  at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
>   at org.apache.hadoop attempt_201401050058_0010_m_000000_0: Temp path:
> ./hipi/0.hib.tmp 14/01/12 02:40:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
> attempt_201401050058_0010_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED Error:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hipi.imagebundle.HipiImageBundle    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
> Downloader$DownloaderMapper.map(Downloader.java:61)   at
> Downloader$DownloaderMapper.map(Downloader.java:1)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)  at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
>   at org.apache.hadoop attempt_201401050058_0010_m_000000_1: Temp path:
> ./hipi/0.hib.tmp 14/01/12 02:40:27 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
> attempt_201401050058_0010_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED Error:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hipi.imagebundle.HipiImageBundle    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
> Downloader$DownloaderMapper.map(Downloader.java:61)   at
> Downloader$DownloaderMapper.map(Downloader.java:1)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)  at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
>   at org.apache.hadoop attempt_201401050058_0010_m_000000_2: Temp path:
> ./hipi/0.hib.tmp 14/01/12 02:40:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job
> complete: job_201401050058_0010 14/01/12 02:40:44 INFO
> mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7 14/01/12 02:40:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:
> Job Counters  14/01/12 02:40:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map
> tasks=1 14/01/12 02:40:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map
> tasks=4 14/01/12 02:40:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map
> tasks=4 14/01/12 02:40:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent
> by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=61598 14/01/12 02:40:44 INFO
> mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied
> slots (ms)=0 14/01/12 02:40:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time
> spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0 14/01/12
> 02:40:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces
> waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you use the commands provided on the HIPI website. Click [HERE](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/examples/downloader.html) to visit the website. Here is the useful command:

> `./runDownloader.sh /hdfs/path/to/list.txt /hdfs/path/to/output.hib 100`

Depending on the Hadoop version that you get, the path names in the build.xml files that come with the HIPI package for creating the jar files will be incorrect. For example, I have downloaded hadoop-1.2.1 but the HIPI library used a much older version. With that, the HIPI team gives this code snippet:

```
<project basedir="." default="all">

  <target name="setup">
  <property name="hadoop.home" value="/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.1" />
  <property name="hadoop.version" value="0.20.1" />
  <property name="hadoop.classpath" value="${hadoop.home}/hadoop-${hadoop.version}-core.jar" />
  <property name="metadata.jar" value="3rdparty/metadata-extractor-2.3.1.jar" />
  </target>
  ...
```

For me, the hadoop.classpath is incorrect. I had to change to

```
<target name="setup">
    <property name="hadoop.home" value="/your/path/hadoop-1.2.1" />
    <property name="hadoop.version" value="1.2.1" />
    <property name="hadoop.classpath" value="${hadoop.home}/hadoop-core-${hadoop.version}.jar" />
    <property name="metadata.jar" value="3rdparty/metadata-extractor-2.3.1.jar" />
  </target>
```

I just had to move the "core" keyword around.

After this, you should be able to:

> `./runDownloader.sh /hdfs/path/to/list.txt /hdfs/path/to/output.hib 100`

Assuming you know the path to your hadoop files system, this should successfully compile your build.xml file and run the program.